# Can You See Something Missing In My Javascript File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to recreate this JSfiddle locally on my machine:

http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/LM8Gd/1/

I don't understand though because it will goto the menu screen like on the fiddle above, but the animations will not happen and the question will not cycle through. It will only stay on the length? question and stay there and none of the buttons will do anything.

I have 3 files: index.html, js.js, and styles.css.

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="js.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- start questionaire -->

<form class="questionnaire">
    <fieldset>
         <h3>length?</h3>

        <label>
            <input name="length" value="5" type="radio" />Too big</label>
        <label>
            <input name="length" value="4" type="radio" />big</label>
        <label>
            <input name="length" value="3" type="radio" />medium</label>
        <label>
            <input name="length" value="2" type="radio" />small</label>
        <label>
            <input name="length" value="1" type="radio" />tiny</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
         <h3>width?</h3>

        <label>
            <input name="width" value="5" type="radio" />Too big</label>
        <label>
            <input name="width" value="4" type="radio" />big</label>
        <label>
            <input name="width" value="3" type="radio" />medium</label>
        <label>
            <input name="width" value="2" type="radio" />small</label>
        <label>
            <input name="width" value="1" type="radio" />tiny</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
         <h3>weight?</h3>

        <label>
            <input name="weight" value="5" type="radio" />Too big</label>
        <label>
            <input name="weight" value="4" type="radio" />big</label>
        <label>
            <input name="weight" value="3" type="radio" />medium</label>
        <label>
            <input name="weight" value="2" type="radio" />small</label>
        <label>
            <input name="weight" value="1" type="radio" />tiny</label>
    </fieldset>
    <button class="back" type="button">back</button>
</form>


<!-- end questionaire -->





</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
        @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */

    .questionnaire label {
        display:block;
        clear:both
    }
    .questionnaire fieldset:not(:first-child) {
        display:none
    }
```

js.js:

```
$(function () {
    $(".questionnaire input[type='radio']").click(function () {
        var fs = $(this).closest("fieldset"),
            next = fs.nextAll('fieldset:first');
        fs.slideUp('fast');
        if (next.length) {
            next.slideDown('fast')
        } else {
            alert("do some computation")
        }
    })
    $(".questionnaire button.back").click(function(){
        var fs=$(this).siblings(":visible"),
            prev=fs.prevAll('fieldset:first');
        if (prev.length){
            fs.slideUp('fast')
            prev.slideDown('fast')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've loaded jQuery into your page which `js.js` depends upon.  There should have been errors in the browser error console or debug console that point you in some useful direction.  If you aren't looking there first when something doesn't work, that's one of the first things to learn.

Comment: that worked.. thank you. make a reply here ill make your answer as correct

Comment: im using dreamweaver, there were no errors.

Comment: There would have been errors in whatever browser you were running it in.

Comment: what kind of error? it only showed the first "slide" and that was it

Comment: The line starting with `$(function () {` would have created a script error because `$` was not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've loaded jQuery into your page which `js.js` depends upon.

There should have been errors in the browser error console or debug console that point you in some useful direction. If you aren't looking there first when something doesn't work, that's one of the first things to learn.